# making http call in nodejs in chain

Tags: node.js, express

how to make http call api in a chain

my requirement is create account

i have to following events

1 check the account is exist or not 
  2 if account is not exists means i have create account

for account exists or not 
 i wrote one function search (account name is unique )

```
 Account.search({"name":"username"})
```

it retrieve the account name with "username"
  if it not found  i am calling Account.save()

Account.da.js

```
exports.search = function (query) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    request({
        url: config.ctxDa.url + "/account/search",
        method: "GET",
        qs: query,
        useQuerystring: true,
        headers: {"Content Type": "application/json"}
    }, function (error, response, body) {


        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            deferred.resolve(body);
        }
        else {
            deferred.reject(error);

        }

    });

    return deferred.promise;

};
```

// for creating account

```
  exports.save = function (newAccount) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();


        request({
            url: config.ctxDa.url + "/account",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content Type": "application/json"},
            json: newAccount

        }, function (error, response, body) {

            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                deferred.resolve(body);
            }
            else {
                deferred.reject(error);

            }

        });

        return deferred.promise;

    };
```

this is my utility function to create account

```
exports.createAccount = function (account) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();


    Account.search({name: account.name}).then(function (body) {

        if (JSON.parse(body).length == 0)
            return;

           return throw  new Error("account already exists");

    }).then(function () {

        return Account.save(account).then(function (body) {

            return deferred.resolve(body);
        }, function (error) {

            throw  error;

        })


    }).catch(function (error) {

        deferred.reject(error);

    })
    .done();


return deferred.promise;


}
```

what is best practice to call http calls in chain order

Comment: It’s not clear to me what your `search` function is returning. Is it supposed to return an empty `body` if the user is not found?

Comment: search function return  empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic should work, although you do not need to create a new promise object in your `createAccount` function. Because both `Account.search` and `Account.save` are returning promises, you can just chain them and return the result:

```
exports.createAccount = function(account) {
  return Account.search({name: account.name}).then(function(body) {
    if (JSON.parse(body).length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    // (you don’t need to `return`; `throw` by itself is enough)
    throw new Error('account already exists');
  }).then(function() {
    return Account.save(account);
  });
}
```

When you chain promises together using a chain of `then()` functions, the return value from the final step of the chain is what is returned to the caller. That’s why we `return Account.search(…)`. It will ultimately return the final promise from that chain of `then()` functions. It will be a rejected promise if there was an error, or else the resolved promise from `Account.save` (which is what was returned by the final `then()` function).

We skipped the `catch` function, because you are simply passing any error up the chain. If there is an error, it will be passed back to the caller of `createAccount` and it’s their responsibility to handle it.

One more way to improve this code would be to handle the `JSON.parse` within the `Account.search` function. Instead of returning the body, it should return the parsed result, so you don’t have to do that in the `createAccount` function (or anywhere else that you may call `Account.search`). And I’m not sure what `Account.save` returns, but it looks like that could be parsed as well, before returning.